# How to crop the map itself in Layout Window of QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I must crop the size of my map into square without moving the frame? Imagine I have A4 size paper and the frame covers the whole paper with around 0.5 margin each side. I need to place the map in the left and some textual information in the right?

How can I crop it to something like this?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: drag the right hand edge of the frame to the left?

Comment: @IanTurton I edited my question. Sorry for that. How can I crop my layout for somethin like that? I tried resizing but the paper is resized

Comment: Are you asking how to create a separate frame item?

Comment: @Erik that would be okay if there's no other way to do it. How can I create it?

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/overview_composer.html?highlight=layout

Comment: What do you mean by 'if there is no other way to do it?'. Combining IanTurton's and Erik's comments will give you exactly what you need. Resize your *Map Frame* (not Layout) to where you want it, and add a text label, or whatever you need, to the right of it to hold your supplementary information.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you so much!